# Wagtail Admin Forms ordering

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have list of Pages in Admin Panel Forms that look like on screenshot.
How can I add chronological sorting for this or some kind of ordering?  I want that pages with new form submissions will appear at top of this list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can build a QuerySet for your model and set the ordering to your needs. Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#page-queryset-ordering),

> you must apply the ordering explicitly when constructing a QuerySet:
>
> ```
> news_items = NewsItemPage.objects.live().order_by('-publication_date')
> ```

Assuming you have a `FormIndex` Page listing the `Form` model, you can update its context like this:

```
class FormIndexPage(Page):
    ...

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['form_entries'] = Form.objects.live().order_by('-your_date_field')
        return context
```

Then use that updated context in your template,

```
{% for entry in form_entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter_form_submissions_for_user hook: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#filter-form-submissions-for-user

```
# wagtail_hooks.py

# Sort submission form list by published time
@hooks.register('filter_form_submissions_for_user')
def submissions_filter(user, queryset):
    return queryset.order_by("-last_published_at")
```